# Unexpected output from skimage local_binary_pattern

Tags: python, scikit-image, lbph-algorithm

I calculate the LBP via this exemplary code:

```
from skimage import feature

radius_lbp = 1
n_points_lbp = 8

temp = feature.local_binary_pattern(regions_arr_lbp[i,j,:], n_points_lbp, radius_lbp, method='uniform').ravel()
```

whereby `regions_arr_lbp[i,j,:]` is a 64x64 numpy array with float64 values.

Now for clarification:

- `exam_pixel` = the pixel we calculate the LBP for
- `neigh_pixel` = the neighborhood pixels of `exam_pixel`

As far as I understand the LBP, I look at the immediate neighborhood of `exam_pixel` and compare its intensity with the intensities of its neigh_pixels. When using the method `'uniform'`, each neigh_pixel whose intensity is greater than `exam_pixel`'s is assigned a 1, and 0 otherwise. This would lead to a theoretical maximum encoded value of 8 for `exam_pixel` if each pixel in `neigh_pixel` has a higher intensity.

However, when I run the code above, I get a maximum encoded value of 9 in my `temp` array multiple times. How is that possible? Have I misunderstood the LBP and how it works?

Comment: Can you provide an example patch of floating point values for which you get 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 9 different rotation-invariant uniform patterns for a neighbourhood of 8 pixels, namely:

- 0: `00000000`
- 1: `00000001`
- 2: `00000011`
- 3: `00000111`
- 4: `00001111`
- 5: `00011111`
- 6: `00111111`
- 7: `01111111`
- 8: `11111111`

For this descriptor to be rotation-invariant the patterns `00000001`, `00000010`, `00000100`, `00001000`, `00010000`, `00100000`, `01000000` and `10000000` are considered the same pattern. The same applies to patterns from 2 to 7.

All the non-uniform patterns (for example `01010101`, `11001100` or `00100100`) are dubbed as 9 and merged into the 10-th bin of the LBP histogram.

Excerpt from the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/v0.22.0/skimage/feature/_texture.pyx) of the `_local_binary_pattern()` function:

```
                        # 1. Constant patterns patterns (with n_ones=0 and
                        # n_ones=P) and non uniform patterns are given fixed
                        # code values.
```